# What are the most effective ways to increase land value?

Tags: simcity-2013

I've seen land value increases with the placement of Hospitals and Fire Houses, I assume parks do the same thing (though it seems like a much smaller increase). What are some effective ways I can get the most land value increase for my simoleon?

If you can expand your answer to discuss both early game increases (I don't have 150k to spend on expensive public works projects) and later in the game, that would be most helpful.

Comment: Check the question on the topic of [abandoned buildings](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/107536/24745). It is possible to bring them back to life, but it takes a lot longer that for them to react to the cause of abandonment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many structures in SimCity create a radius zone when you place them, this radiant is shown as either a circle around the structure or dots along the roads depending on the kind of structure you're placing. Parks and plazas create a radius zone, as do schools and police. Each of these structures provides an increase to land value for properties within that area.

The size of the area that is within the radius depends on the structure being placed, parks and plazas will affect a smaller area in comparison to police stations or fire stations. Placing multiple parks or plazas with their radius zones overlapping will stack, providing a greater increase in value.

Any specialisation you choose for your city will also have an affect on land value, for example specialising in Casinos will increase the value of commercial buildings in its vicinity.

Ensuring that you keep the streets of your city clean will provide you with a boost to land value, whilst letting them get backed up or not dealing with sewage will have a negative effect on your land value.

Abandoned buildings will also have a negative effect on the land value of nearby buildings, and have an increased chance of catching fire. Keeping abandoned buildings around over the long term will drive down land value for the surrounding area and it is usually recommended that once the building goes 'dark'. It is better to bulldoze that building to prevent it from causing damage to the value of the surrounding buildings.

Comment: Keeping your city clean and free of abandoned buildings will keep it from lowering the land value of surrounding areas.

Comment: Any more details you can provide on the relative weights of the increase in land value would be appreciated, and perhaps some details on what kinds of specialized buildings improve which zones.

Comment: police stations increase land value, however if a police station has a jail full of criminals, it decreases land value. I believe this is because when the jail is full criminals are released.

Comment: solution: make sure your jails don't get full...

Answer (score 0):

Roads!  I was just working on it and I thought roads only needed upgrading based on congestion.  All it took was a good upgrade and poof instant size increase and a nice fat reward from the tax base.

Comment: I don't think upgrading roads increases land value directly, but simply that your buildings were prevented from upgrading because your roads were not at a proper level.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, health buildings, anti fire buildings, and police buildings. The better the building in these three categories, the better your land value. For the buildings to get better land value they have to be inside the radius. To see the radius, you have to click on the building and it will show you the radius. Schools also help land value.

Overflow of criminals will decrease land value (to avoid this build better schools and bigger police structures.

Abandoned buildings will be at a fire risk so they will also decrease land value.

Parks will also help, but they have a smaller radius.

Answer (score -1):

Pollution and crime lower land value. 2 small fountain parks in formal park section should raise the nearby places too wealthy. You don't always want high wealth because they are very sensitive too pollution, crime, and high taxes.