# What is the relationship between zone density and wealth?

Tags: simcity-2013

I am wondering if there is a relationship between a zone density and residential wealth? For example, do high wealth Sims only live in high density areas?

Also, how do you get high density industrial? I've tried placing parks around my industrial zones but I did not notice any change in my density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a relationship between a zone density and residential wealth? For example, do high wealth Sims only live in high density areas?

There is no relationship.  There are LD, MD, HD versions for LW, MW and HW.  All residential buildings start at LD and move up to HD as they accumulate [happiness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107773/how-can-i-increase-the-density-of-residential-zones) (and as space and roads permit).

> Also, how do you get high density industrial? I've tried placing parks around my industrial zones but I did not notice any change in my density.

HD industry is 8x4, which is to say, 8 street widths must adjoin the road - it is twice as long as MD industry.

For comparison: LD industry is 4x2.  MD industry is 4x4.

You might be trying to get High Tech industrial.  T1 is the starting tech level.  T2 is reached by students attending Community College.  T3 is reached by students attending University (or by Vu Tower).  You can go directly from T1 to T3.  Refer to the tech level dataview (the gear icon).

Answer (score 4):

High wealth $$$ residential areas are created by desirability:

- Services
- Parks
- Lack of Pollution
- etc...

Whereas high density R buildings are created by having happiness

- having money
- being able to buy stuff
- etc

For Industrial land value has no influence on density/tech level at all! Density for all tech levels can be easily increased by having freight deliveries (ie depot with a freight bin) and for high tech visits from a Fire Marshall. [That's why the second you build a trade depot your Ind bar will be solid yellow for the rest of the game even if you have a fraction of the workers needed]

High tech buildings are created by 'desirability' -- in this case being 'near' a college/univ.

refer to: imgur.com/a/gUFqn